# Multiple separator in .txt file

Tags: r, import, txt

I am importing data from a .txt file to `R`. A sample how the .txt data looks is presented here:

```
000003154|OAKLEAF FOREST TENANT MANAGEMENT ||1706 GREENLEAF DR|NORFOLK|VA|23523-2112|US|03|

000065837|OHIO STATE GRANGE OF PATRONS OF HUSBANDRY|64 HURON COUNTY POMONA|4655 STATE ROUTE 60|WAKEMAN|OH|44889-8602|US|05|

000107893|INTERNATIONAL ASSOCIATION OF LIONS|CLUBSSTURBRIDGE LION|204 OLD SPRINGFIELD RD|STAFFORD SPGS|CT|06076-3016|US|

000262358|KEY CLUB INTERNATIONAL||H90622 HANFORD WEST HIGH SCHOOL|1150 W LACEY BLVD|HANFORD|CA|93230-3575|US|04|

000267075|INTERNATIONAL ASSOCIATION OF LIONS|CLUBSBRUNSWICK G|3324 KELWIN AVE|BRUNSWICK|GA|31520-3741|US|04|
```

The crucial thing to notice here is is that most of the time the relevant separator in this file is `|`. But *sometimes* it appears twice `||`. This means that when I import the data with a code like `read.delim("data.txt", header=F,sep="|")`, `R` creates an extra column when one of the observations has a double separator. Do you have any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the file before reading it? For example in linux or macos in commnad line: sed  "s/\|\|/\|/" data.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can read it with the `readr` package:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

text_file <- read_file("~/Desktop/tekst.txt")

text_file2 <- gsub("\\|\\|", "\\|", text_file)
text_df <- unlist(strsplit(text_file2, split = "\\\n"))

data.frame(col = text_df) %>%
  filter(col != "") %>%
  mutate(col = str_split_fixed(col, "\\|", 10))
```